# Dynamic queryset with current date for a ModelChoiceField in a ModelForm

Tags: django, modelform

I have read many similar questions, but no one clarifies if it's launched just when we run the server by first time, or every time we refresh the page in the browser.

I have a ModelForm like this:

```
class TestForm(ModelForm):
    field1 = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Model.objects.filter(datetime=datetime.today()))
```

And if I ran the server yesterday and I refresh the page today, I still have the objects with yesterday's datetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your queryset is evaluated once, when the server first loads.

The solution is to set the queryset in the form's `__init__` method, so that the queryset is evaluated each time the form is instantiated.

```
class TestForm(ModelForm):
    # Use the empty qs .none() here, we override it in __init__ anyway
    field1 = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Model.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field1'].queryset = Model.objects.filter(datetime=datetime.today())
```

Comment: This looks good. But... the last line may be : self.fields['field1'].queryset = Model.objects.filter(datetime=datetime.today()) ?

Answer (score 2):

The code you have will be run once at server startup. If you want that the date is checked on every page refresh you can pass the `datetime.today` function instead of the value:

```
class TestForm(ModelForm):
    field1 = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Model.objects.filter(datetime=datetime.today))
```

Comment: Support for passing callables to queryset arguments was deprecated in Django 1.7, and removed in 1.9 ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-9)).

Answer (score 0):

[Starting with Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/database-functions/#now) it is possible to obtain current time at the query level:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now
Model.objects.filter(datetime=Now())
```

`Now()` will be be evaluated at the time of query execution (rather than when `Now()` is executed in the Python code). Note, however, that `Now()` reports time as known to the database server.